# Moving LOB size more than actual size

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

```
SELECT BYTES/ (1024*1024*1024) GB
 FROM DBA_SEGMENTS D
 JOIN DBA_LOBS L ON L.SEGMENT_NAME = D.SEGMENT_NAME
WHERE D.OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND SEGMENT_NAME = 'MY_LOB'
```

| GB |
| --- |
| 100 |

Actual LOB object size = 100 GB, but when moving LOB to another tablespace it takes up more space than 100 GB.

Oracle version 19c.

How to find the exact moving size LOB object ?

Comment: Not sure if you just mean `dbms_log.getlength()`? How do you know the actual LOB size, how are you moving it, and do you have compression and/or encryption enabled for either LOB column?

Comment: Please show the DDL you are using to move the LOB and how much larger than 100GB it is ending up. Also check the block sizes of the origin and target tablespace. A chunk cannot be smaller than the block size so if there's a difference there there might be additional wasted space if the LOBs are slightly larger than 4KB. Lastly, make sure to include owner in your join from dba_lobs and dba_segments to preclude the possibility of there being two LOBs with the same name owned by different schemas (unlikely)

Comment: alter table TABLE move lob (COLUMN) store as segment_name ( tablespace TBS) nologging parallel 4 online;

Comment: compression disabled

Comment: The size of the lob segment = 100GB, during the moving of the lob file to another tablespace I keep an eye on the tablespace, it grows by almost 200 GB

Comment: @AleksRous, tablespace growth can exceed segment growth, as it's controlled by autoextend parameters. Is the actual LOB segment 200GB after the move? Rerun the query against `dba_segments` and verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possibilities

1 - you are not taking into account the LOB index segment (although these are typically small relative to the LOB segment itself)

2 - you are comparing the sum of the lob contents with the anticipated segment size.  Depending on your characterset, this can be out by a factor 2, eg

```
SQL> select * from dba_segments
  2  where tablespace_name = 'LARGETS';

no rows selected

SQL> select * from dba_segments
  2  where tablespace_name = 'LARGETS';

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL> create table t
  2  ( x int, c clob ) tablespace largets;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t
  2  select rownum, rpad('x',32000,'x')
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 1024*1024*1024/32000;

33554 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select sum(dbms_lob.getlength(c))
  2  from t;

SUM(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(C))
--------------------------
                1073728000

SQL> select segment_name
  2  from   user_lobs
  3  where  table_name = 'T';

SEGMENT_NAME
------------------------------
SYS_LOB0000177878C00002$$

SQL> select bytes/ (1024*1024) gb
  2  from dba_segments d
  3  where segment_name = 'SYS_LOB0000177878C00002$$';

        GB
----------
   2240.25

SQL> select segment_name, bytes
  2  from dba_segments
  3  where tablespace_name = 'LARGETS';

SEGMENT_NAME                        BYTES
------------------------------ ----------
T                                 2097152
SYS_IL0000177878C00002$$            65536
SYS_LOB0000177878C00002$$      2349072384
```

LOBS in multibyte characterset databases are stored in UCS2 format, so 2 bytes per character.